# MySQL, count total numbers of each IDs in two or more tables

Tags: mysql

I have 3 individual students `(table_student)`, each student have attended 3 classes `(table_class_1, table_class_2, table_class_3)`

Image below are the list of student table (table_student), class 1 `(table_class_1)`, class 2 `(table_class_2)` and class 3 `(table_class_3)` together with the total result of each of the class table.

[image]

My goal is to count how many times each students has entered each of the classes. So my expected result would be as shown as image below

[image]

What I can do so far was using union but the result is not what i expected to be

```
SELECT COUNT(B.student_id) AS count_class_1, NULL, NULL FROM table_student A
INNER JOIN table_class_1 B ON A.id = B.student_id
WHERE B.student_id = 1

UNION

SELECT NULL, COUNT(B.student_id) AS count_class_2, NULL  FROM table_student A
INNER JOIN table_class_2 B ON A.id = B.student_id
WHERE B.student_id = 1

UNION

SELECT NULL, NULL, COUNT(B.student_id) AS count_class_3 FROM table_student A
INNER JOIN table_class_3 B ON A.id = B.student_id
WHERE B.student_id = 1
```

[image]

Comment: i think i provided minimal reproducible example for my questions...

Comment: And fix your schema. You have 3 tables where you should have only 1

Comment: my questions is to query for 3 tables...how am i suppose to explain if i only use 1 table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recomend having one table for classes.

But what you whant is possible too:

```
SELECT
    ts.id,
    ts.student_name,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_class_1 tc1 WHERE tc1.student_id = ts.id) c1,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_class_2 tc2 WHERE tc2.student_id = ts.id) c2,
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table_class_3 tc3 WHERE tc3.student_id = ts.id) c3
FROM
    table_student ts
ORDER BY
    ts.student_name
;
```

Comment: hmmm, the result is `stud_2 | 117 | 117 | 117`

Comment: I've forgot the main part `GROUP BY` :) Please consider changing your schema. This is a wise advice.

Comment: i will consider, but from your answer, i got `stud_1 | 48 | 48 | 48` http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0b44f1/4

Comment: OK. My bad. Here is what you want :)

Comment: how do I display sum of students at the end of each rows?

Comment: You already have the parts of this sum. For this example you can warp this query into another query and do ```SELECT id, name, c1, c2, c3, c1+c2+c3 as total FROM (query)```

Comment: i got `Unknown column 'c1' in 'field list'`

Answer (score 1):

Your tables are not normalized correctly which is part of the reason you are facing this challenge. Have three tables as follows:

```
table_student (id, student_name),
table_class (id, class_name),
table_student_class(id, table_student_id, table_class_id)
```

Populate the data to the tables and to get the student attendance count use the following statement.

```
select table_student_id, table_class_id, Count(id) as class_count 
from table_student_class 
group by table_student_id, table_class_id
```

The results will be a class attendance count for each student.

Comment: And handle any remaining display issues in application code